# redux-saga twice called - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I'mg using redux-saga. 
My saga implementation is called for twice when I call it just one.

my saga:

```
export function* api(parms) {

    try {

        //when parms hasnt a uv key, it's a local calling
        if(!parms['uv']){

            yield put(publish(parms,parms['action']));
            return
        }

        //to check user_id if the user is login - from local storage
        if(isLogin()){

            if(!parms['user_id'])
                parms['user_id'] = getData('USER').user_id;
        }

        //to create token
        parms['tok']    = getToken(parms,parms['uv'])
        parms['time']   = todayForamted;


        var formData = new FormData()
        for ( var key in parms ) {
            formData.append(key, parms[key]);
        }
        var requestOptions = {}
        requestOptions.body = formData


        // Call our request helper (see 'utils/request')
        const response = yield call(request, baseUrl+parms['uv'], requestOptions);


        yield put(done(response,parms['uv']));
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error',err)
        yield put(error(err));

    }
}



/**
 * Root saga manages watcher lifecycle
 */
export default function* watcherApi() {
    yield takeLatest([Uva2,Uva3,Uva8,Uva10,Uva11,Uva19,Uva20,Uva46,current_tr], api);

}
```

`[Uva2,Uva3,Uva8,Uva10,Uva11,Uva19,Uva20,Uva46,current_tr]` are my unique keys.

my actions:

```
export function getFinanceOfUsersByUserId(parms) {
  return {
    type: Uva19,
    ...parms,
  };
}


export function done(res,uv) {
  return {
    type: DONE,
    uv:uv,
    ...res,
  };
}

export function error(error) {
  return {
    type: ERROR,
    error,
  };
}
```

my component connection:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {

    var responsiveObj = state.get('api').get('responsiveObj')

    if(!responsiveObj)
        return {}
     else
        return {'responsiveObj':responsiveObj}   

  }

const withConnect = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
   // mapDispatchToProps,
);


const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'api', 'reducer':apiReducer });
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'api', saga });

export default compose(
    withReducer,
    withSaga,
    withConnect,
)(Index);
```

inside my `componentDidMount` function:

```
this.props.dispatch(getFinanceOfUsersByUserId({'uv':'Uva19'}))
```

all of my actins called twice!

Comment: Perhaps, two constants have the same value: `Uva19`

Comment: @Alex `all of my actins called twice!`.

Comment: Could you have invoked `watcherApi` saga twice (i.e. `yield fork(watcherApi)` or `sagaMiddleware.run(watcherApi)`)? The `watcherApi` is like a `while(true){...}` under the hood, and could only be explicitly cancelled.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: If you are on React 18, strict mode might be the reason:
https://dev.to/ag-grid/react-18-avoiding-use-effect-getting-called-twice-4i9e